# Does git pull origin <branch> creates index.lock?

Tags: git, github

index.lock file get created on .git folder of git repository. It helps to check if there is any operation is going on or not. But when i do **git pull origin**, index.lock file is not getting created.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not clear *why* you are asking about this.  The index is also called the staging area, or sometimes the cache—these are all the same thing.  You're not, in general, supposed to have to worry about how it works internally, but Git needs to lock the index whenever it needs to update the index.  Git thus creates an `index.lock` file in these cases.

`git pull` runs `git fetch` followed by a second Git command, typically `git merge`.

`git fetch` does not need to lock the index (ever) because it never updates the index.

`git merge` does one of several different things depending on what you ask it to merge and what flags you give it.  The `git pull` command can pass `--no-ff` to `git merge` so as force a particular operation in some cases, but if you don't use that, you get:

- Nothing, if there is nothing to merge.
- A *fast-forward* operation if the current commit is strictly behind the commit you (or `git pull`) ask `git merge` to merge.
- A true merge if the current commit and the to-be-merged commit have diverged from some common ancestor (the *merge base*).

When `git merge` does nothing, it does not affect the index, so it does not create an `index.lock` file.  In the other two cases, it *does* affect the index, so it does create an `index.lock` file.

(Note that `git checkout` will also create an `index.lock` file when it updates the index.)

You cannot tell whether `git merge` will do anything until after the `git fetch` step completes, so it is not possible to predict in advance whether `git pull` will create an `index.lock` file.

The above reasoning also holds for the case where you instruct `git pull` to run `git rebase` instead of running `git merge`.  The actual arguments to `git rebase` depend on what `git fetch` fetches, and `git rebase` will do nothing if there is nothing to do, but will do things (and hence possibly create `index.lock`) when there are things to do.  What there is to do, if anything, depends on the result of the `git fetch`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed description. I was performing some operations on git using Perl script. When i execute some command, i was monitoring the index.lock in order to know whether the execution was finished or not. That is where this doubt arises when I do git pull. Thanks again.

Comment: If you run a Git command from some other command, you can simply wait for the Git command to finish, after which it's, well, finished...